# AngularJS Touch Carousel

Tags: angularjs

This is a follow-up to one of my previous questions and it is what I'm looking far but I can't seem to get it working. This is what I'm trying to work with [here](https://github.com/revolunet/angular-carousel) and this is what I've tried:

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <title>Building Angular Directives</title>

    <link href="css/angular-carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>

    <!-- Angular Components -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "angular/angular-mocks.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "angular/angular-loader.js"></script>

    <!-- App definition -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "app.js"></script>

    <!-- Directives -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "directives/my-directives.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "controllers/my-controllers.js"></script>

    <!-- Custom Carousel -->
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "js/angular-carousel.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
 <div ng-controller = "HomeController">
        <section remembered at-greeting='customer'
                 equals-greeting='customer'
                 amper-greeting='getGreeting()'>
        </section>
        <hr/>
        <ul rn-carousel class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="image in sportImages">
                <div class="layer">{{image}}</div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

**my-controllers.js**

```
myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    // Test
    $scope.greeting = "Hello World - from the controller";

    $scope.sportImages = [
        'http://placekitten.com/g/200/300',
        'http://placekitten.com/g/200/301',
        'http://placekitten.com/g/200/303'
    ];

}]);
```

And I declare a dependency on the angular-dependency during the applications creation:

**app.js**

```
var myApp = angular.module( 'myApp',['angular-carousel'] );
```

Nothing appears on the screen and nothing appears in the error console which suggests that everything is being loaded - perhaps just not in the correct order?

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The actual reason why it wasn't working was because of the height not being set in the CSS for the unordered list, as well as a misunderstanding of how it works.

Here's a working [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VruPSSkVK47YgeUwYO7l?p=preview) of it working with all the animations currently available. Though I will be refining this to move out the internal styling and package the whole thing in a new directive.

And the code just in case it disappears from Plunkr:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

<head>
    <title>Building Angular Directives</title>
    <link href="css/angular-carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <style>
        ul {
            height:300px;
            width: 600px;
            background:blue;
        }
        img.alignLeft {
            float: left;
        }
    </style>

    <!-- Angular Components -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="angular/angular-carousel.js"></script>

    <!-- App definition -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controllers/my-controllers.js"></script> 
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="HomeController">
        <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-controls class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="images in kittens">
                <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-transition="slide" class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="images in kittens">
                <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-transition="zoom" class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="images in kittens">
                <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-transition="hexagon" class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="images in kittens">
                <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-transition="slideAndFade" class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="images in kittens">
                <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
        <ul rn-carousel rn-carousel-auto-slide rn-carousel-transition="none" class="image">
            <li ng-repeat="images in kittens">
                <div ng-repeat="image in images">
                    <img class="alignLeft" ng-src="{{image}}"/>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <hr/>
    </div>
</body>
```

And here is the collection in the HomeController that I'm using:

```
$scope.kittens = [
        ['http://placekitten.com/g/200/300','http://placekitten.com/g/200/301','http://placekitten.com/g/200/303'],
        ['http://placekitten.com/g/200/301','http://placekitten.com/g/200/303','http://placekitten.com/g/200/300'],
        ['http://placekitten.com/g/200/303','http://placekitten.com/g/200/300','http://placekitten.com/g/200/301']
    ];
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem and solved it this way:

html:

```
<ul rn-carousel class="image">
        <li ng-repeat="image in images">
            <div class="layer" ng-class="{'last':$last}"><img data-ng-src='{{image}}' /></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

and css:

```
    li {
        position: relative !important;
        display: block !important;
    }
    .layer{
        position:absolute !important;
    }
    .last{
        position: inherit !important;
    }
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question? Is it a comment on another answer?

Answer (score 0):

I remember having to set a height to force it open, something like.

```
 .layer { height:300px }
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't make a difference

Comment: Maybe it was on the img, I just remember it was loading and I could see the elements in the inspector so just I messed with the CSS there in chrome dev tools.